# Facebook Like Button Not Showing Admin Page or Linking To Ap

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm using Facebook's Like Button. Facebook tells me that if I place the App ID meta tag and call it in the FB.init, I should be able to track the likes and insights from my like button via my app. However, the "Admin Page" does not show up on the like button, and the like button does not seem to be registered with my App.

I've gone through the linter, and it shows all my information correctly.

I've seen similar posts elsewhere, but no one has an answer.

My code:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="MY TITLE"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="MY URL"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="MY IMAGE"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MY SITE NAME"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY NUMERIC APP ID"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="MY DESCRIPTION"/>

    <div><div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
              window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: 'MY NUMERIC APP ID', 
                    status: true, 
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true,
                    channelUrl : 'MY CHANNEL URL'
                    });
              };
              (function() {
                    var e = document.createElement('script');
                    e.type = 'text/javascript';
                    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                    e.async = true;
                    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
                  }());
        </script>

    <fb:like href="MY URL" send="true" width="400" show_faces="true" font="arial" action="like"></fb:like></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to track Insights for your domain is by claiming your domain at www.facebook.com/insights. When you log in to that url, we will associate the domain with the admin tag found on the page and allow anyone who is an admin of the app to view the insights.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the admin link you need to like the page yourself first. You also need to be logged in to Facebook with an account that is an admin of the application linked in the fb:app_id tag.

Comment: I've liked the page myself, as well as I am the admin of the app; I'm the one that created it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one of your meta tags required for the administrative features. Add in this line with the user IDs of your administrators.

`<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>`

Comment: You don't need both, just 1 or the other.

Comment: Ahh jeff is right, I just tried. @John - Have you re-[linted](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) your page?